# Orfeo Toolbox output rasters are 300x larger than inputs of the same size

Tags: raster, geoprocessing, command-line, orfeo-toolbox, smoothing

I am trying to use [Orfeo Toolbox CLI](https://www.orfeo-toolbox.org/CookBook/CliInterface.html) to do some processing, e.g. Smoothing:

```
otbcli_Smoothing -in path/to/mosaic.tif -out output/smoothing.tif uint8 -type mean
```

For now, the input, `mosaic.tif`, is just full of zeros and datatype `uint8`. The problem is that while the input file is approx. 9Kb, the output is 3.7Mb.

When I run `gdalinfo mosaic.tif`:

```
> Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF Files:
> Size is 1014, 722 Coordinate System is: PROJCRS["ETRS89 / TM35FIN(E,N)",
> ... 
> Image Structure Metadata:  COMPRESSION=LZW  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL 
> ... 
>
> Band 1 Block=256x256 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Gray
> Band 2 Block=256x256 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Undefined
> Band 3 Block=256x256 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Undefined
> Band 4 Block=256x256 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Undefined
> Band 5 Block=256x256 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Undefined
```

When I run `gdalinfo smoothing.tif`:

```
> Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF Files:
> Size is 1014, 722 Coordinate System is: PROJCRS["ETRS89 / TM35FIN(E,N)",
> ... 
> Image Structure Metadata:   INTERLEAVE=PIXEL 
> ... 
> Band 1 Block=1014x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Gray 
> Band 2 Block=1014x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Undefined
> Band 3 Block=1014x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Undefined
> Band 4 Block=1014x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Undefined
> Band 5 Block=1014x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Undefined
```

So there are some differences (the part not shown is identical) but I don't know if (and how) that explains the explosion of the file size. I've checked that the output is the same datatype, `uint8`.

**Question:** What causes the output to be so much larger and how can I deal with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `mosaic.tif` is compressed while `smoothing.tif` is not:

`Image Structure Metadata:  COMPRESSION=LZW`

I don't have any experience with orfeo, but it seems you can pass GDAL creation options to create compressed outputs by using an "extended filename", see:

- https://www.orfeo-toolbox.org/CookBook-6.6.1/AdvancedUse.html#examples
- https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/gtiff.html#creation-options

Comment: That was it, thank you! I just needed to change this:  output/smoothing.tif  to this: "output/smoothing.tif?&gdal:co:COMPRESS=LZW". Note the quotation marks that have to be added.